# How to check specific email validation in phonegap android

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I had created an registration form in which i had created and email i had provided validation to all the filed but I'm confused how to give validation to email field because i want that email should be either gmail.com or yahoomail.com if some one enters any other email even yahoomail.co.in it should give error message.
here is the code i which  checking that its having @ and . in the email or not

```
var atdrate=email.indexOf("@");
var dot1=email.indexOf(".");

else if(atdrate<1 || dot1<1)
    {
        alert("Enter valid Email");
        if(gml<atdrate+1)
            alert("Enter  a vaild mail id");
        else if(yml<atdrate+1)
            alert("Enter a valid email id");

    }
```

Comment: why don't you try match("@gmail.com") or match("@yahoomail.com")?

Comment: Use Regular Expression

Comment: can you give and example how to use it exactly plz NightWhisper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Regular Expressions is probably the best way.  Here's an example ([live demo](http://jsbin.com/ozeyag/19)):

```
function validateEmail(email) { 
    var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\
".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA
-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
}
```

But keep in mind that one should not rely only upon JavaScript validation.  JavaScript can  easily be disabled.  This should be validated on the server side as well.

*answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/46181/1521984

**Update:** Then use the [JavaScript split() function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) to split the mail address after the '@' and check the value versus your strings.

```
var mail = yourMailAdress.split("@");
if (mail[1] == "gmail.com" || mail[1] == "yahoomail.com") {
    // OKAY
} else {
    // false
}
```

Comment: but using regular expression will validate all type of email i want that it should only have gmail.com or yahoomail.com after @ sign

Comment: then simply put the hosters (gmail.com, yahoomail.com) in your regex after the '@'

Comment: thanks for your answer but i don't want to use regular expression i want to try it without using regularexpression

Comment: hey F481 i wrote the code which u gave me in this wave  email=xyz@yahoomail.com mail=email.split("@")                            frmt1='yahoomail.com' and frmt2='gmail.com'       else if(mail[1]!=frmt1 || mail[1]!=frmt2)
  {
    alert("Enter valid Email"); 
    
  } its not give alert window that enter valid email can you tell whats wrong or where im laking

Comment: Recheck your code! The 'else'-clause is wrong there. Perhaps you can debug the script with [firebug](https://getfirebug.com/)?

Comment: on the top of my answer, on the left side you can see a hook (under the 0). When you check/click this hook, you're done! :)

Comment: Please note that deactivating JavaScript on iOS will not affect your cordova apps. They are still able to run JavaScript, even if it is deactivated in your settings.